# Separate records that has no pair

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

[image: Query]

In the image above is the sample list of `Serial#` and `Part#` that I've retrieved from my database.

Every PN must have a paired PN

like this:

P04-000001-**00111**-V000 = P04-000001-**10111**-V000

```
P04-000001-00111-V000

P04-000001-10111-V000
```

**1** means low partnumber and **0** means high partnumber.

My requirement is just to exclude or just tag rows that has excess or has no pair which SN **8**.

I'm still finding ways how to solve this, so I've not posted yet what I tried.

Comment: What variety of SQL?  MySQL?  Oracle?  MS SQL Server?  etc?

Comment: The last two rows (SN 12 and 13) don't seem to match according to your criteria (`00111` and `10111`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to generate a id that you can pair up your rows with. Use a full outer join to get rows with no match from both `C0` and `C1`.

```
with C0 as
(
  select SN,
         PN,
         row_number() over(partition by PN order by SN) as rn
  from YourTable
  where substring(PN, 12, 1) = 0
),
C1 as
(
  select SN,
         PN,
         row_number() over(partition by PN order by SN) as rn
  from YourTable
  where substring(PN, 12, 1) = 1
)
select coalesce(C0.SN, C1.SN) as SN, *
from C0
  full outer join C1
    on C0.PN = stuff(C1.PN, 12, 1, '0') and
       C0.rn = C1.rn
where C0.SN is null or
      C1.SN is null
```

Try on [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58818)

Answer (score 0):

It seem you need to organize your data in a different way to insure you always have a pair. This following should at least show you PN's that do not have enough Paired PN's according to your requirements.

```
SELECT TT1.PN
, LEFT(TT1.PN, 11) + '1' + RIGHT(TT1.PN, 9) AS PairedPN
, COUNT(TT1.SN) AS PNCount
, (SELECT COUNT(TT2.PN)
    FROM YourTable TT2
    WHERE TT2.PN = LEFT(TT1.PN, 11) + '1' + RIGHT(TT1.PN, 9)) AS PairedPNCount
FROM YourTable TT1
WHERE SUBSTRING(TT1.PN, 12, 1) = '0'
GROUP BY TT1.PN
HAVING COUNT(TT1.SN) - (SELECT COUNT(TT2.PN)
            FROM YourTable TT2
            WHERE TT2.PN = LEFT(TT1.PN, 11) + '1' + RIGHT(TT1.PN, 9)) <> 0
```